How to prevent new line in contenteditable if
If reach the maximum height size set. I looked on the website but didn't find anything. Even without pressing the enter key. Using CSS if possible or JS.
<div class="user-input" contenteditable="true"></div>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe avoid using contenteditable in the first place. Use textarea for mult-line input, then you can specify a size limit.

@Barmar Sorry for the late reply, but I need it to be contenteditable because of the alignment issues and everything...
